# Let $A$ be an invertible matrix. Find a singular value decomposition for $A^*$ and $A^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, singular-values

> Let $A$ be an invertible matrix, and let $A = W\Sigma V^*$ be its singular value decomposition. Find a singular value decomposition for $A^*$ and $A^{-1}$.

If we take the conjugate transpose, we get $A^*=V\Sigma^* W^*=V\Sigma W^*$ since $\Sigma$ only has real diagonal entries. **But how do we know the singular values of $A$ are the singular values of $A^*$?**

Similarly, we have $A^{-1}=V\Sigma^{-1}W^*$. **But how do we know the singular values of $A$ are the singular values of $A^{-1}$?**

Comment: You need to characterise the SVD inductively in terms of norms and suitable subspaces. However, **any** time you have $A= U \Sigma V^*$ with $\Sigma$ diagonal with non negative entries then you have a SVD.

Comment: It is worth studying the subspace characterisation. To some degree, this is the whole point of the SVD.

Comment: What do you mean by subspace characterization?

Comment: The first singular value is given by $\|A\|$ and any vector for which $\|Av\| = \sigma_1 \|v\|$ is a corresponding singular vector. The next singular value is the norm of $A$ restricted to the orthogonal complement of $v$, etc, etc. See Golub & Van Loan's "Matrix Computations" for more details.

Comment: Here is a nice writeup by a frequent MSE contributor: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/singular-value-decomposition/

Comment: Actually, this is the characterisation I was really looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_principle_for_singular_values

Answer (score 3):

From the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) of singular-value decomposition, singular values are the diagonal entries $\sigma_i$ in $\Sigma$.

1. You already gave a decomposition $A^*=V\Sigma W^*$. Since $A$ and $A^*$ have the same $\Sigma$ in their decompositions, they have the same singular values.
2. You also gave a decomposition $A^{-1}=V\Sigma^{-1}W^*$. So if $\sigma_i$ is a singular value of $A$, then $1/\sigma_i$ is the singular value of $A^{-1}$. Don't worry about $\sigma_i=0$. It does not happen because $A$ is non-singular.

Comment: We can write $A^*=V\Sigma W^*$, how do we know this is indeed a singular value decomposition?

Comment: Because $V$ and $W$ are unitary, and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with nonnegative real entries.

Comment: Don't we need to check that $W$ is the matrix of eigenvectors of $AA^*$?

Comment: @AlJebr Any SVD satisfies that property, so you don't worry about that. For example, if $A=W\Sigma V^*$ is a SVD, then $A^*=V\Sigma W^*$ and so the diagonalization $AA^*=W\Sigma^2W^*$ gives the information of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $AA^*$ what you wanted to check.